# Create DropDownList in Razor Engine MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have a page for insert new row in some table in my Database.One field is a foreign key from parent in same table.So i want a drobdownlist for user to choosing parent.
This is my table definition :

```
Id          Integer
ParentId_Fk Integer
Body        Varchar
Title       Varchar
```

Create page View :

```
@model MVCDrLaptop.Models.Education

@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <title>Create</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

    @using (Html.BeginForm()) {
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Education</legend>

            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Title)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Title)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Title)
            </div>

            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Text)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Text)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Text)
            </div>

            <div class="editor-field">
                //here is for parentId_FK DropDownList
            </div>

            <p>
                <input type="submit" value="Create" />
            </p>
        </fieldset>
    }

    <div>
        @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

So What should i write for creating my DropDownList?

Comment: Visit http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/javascript/working-with-the-dropdownlist-box-and-jquery/using-the-dropdownlist-helper-with-aspnet-mvc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly get all the values from the database.

Controller:

```
    IEnumerable<SelectListItem> items = from value in values
                                        select new SelectListItem
                                        {
                                          Text = value.ToString(),
                                          Value = value.ToString(),
                                          Selected = value == selectedMovie,
                                         };
    ViewBag.MovieType = items;
```

View:

```
    @Html.DropDownList("items")
```

Answer (score 3):

`@Html.DropDownListFor` and then apply the fields your require from your model.

Here's an example of using DropDownList and DropDownListFor http://blinkingcaret.wordpress.com/2012/08/11/using-html-dropdownlistfor/